# Meteor Collection - How to mark a property as unique

Tags: meteor

How can I mark a property in a Meteor Collection as unique? I am trying to create a document collection with each document having a name that is unique, and I can't figure out how to make this unique.

Answer (score 3):

You know that mongo assigns a unique, non-human based _id to every document, and that often the title a user decides to call something doesn't need to be unique.  That being said,

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/ tells you how to make an index that forces a field to be unique:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

You can run that from the mongo shell.  It can also be called from the server js only.  If you've created a collection by

```
Diaries = new Meteor.collection();
```

then just after adding the collection, in server code, you could add

```
Diaries.ensureIndex({ title: 1},{ unique: true });
```